# RxMoya downgrade Alamofire to 4.9.1, but i need to use Alamofire 5+

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, rx-swift

The main problem is am using currently Moya on my app, but I want to use some functions from "Moya/RxSwift" pod, the problem I am having is when i change the pod the Alamofire downgrades to 4.9.1 and produce a lot of error in the code, there is a way to edit the pod file to keep using Alamofire 5?

My PODS in the podfile:

```html
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, ’10.0’
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

def core_pods
    #core
    pod 'ZXingObjC'
    pod 'Moya/RxSwift'
    pod 'RxSwift'
    pod 'RxCocoa'
    pod 'RxViewModel'
    pod 'XCGLogger', '~> 6.1.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'CryptoSwift', :git => "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift", :branch => "master"
    pod 'AFDateHelper'
    #pod 'Fabric'
    #pod 'Crashlytics'
end

def ui_pods
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'CropViewController'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
end
```

examples of some errors i got on the code because of the downgrade:
[image]

Comment: Which version of `Moya` you are using? Release notes say Alamofire 5.0 is used since Moya version 14.0.0. https://github.com/Moya/Moya/releases

Comment: currently the proyect uses Moya 14.0.0, but when i replace moya with moya/rxswift it makes a downgrade to moya 13.0.1